# Installing an application on Ubuntu (new user)

Tags: ssh

I am not familiar with Linux and have a very simple question. Also couldn't find a similar thread.

I'm connected to Linux remotely from Windows. Whenever try to install an application, it returns 'authentication failed' error. I asked the admin and he answered "try ssh x forward". I read a little bit about ssh but couldn't figure out how and why ssh works for this problem. Thanks for your help.  What is the exact command that I should try to install a program?

Comment: What do you mean by "connected to Linux remotely?" Using SSH? VNC? RDP? Something else? Can you provide an example of an application you wish to install?

Comment: I tried putty, vnc and mstsc.exe.

Comment: For instance, I wanted to install VNC but I couldn't because I am not in sudoers file. The admin installed it for me. But before installation he suggested to try ssh x forwarding and my question is that how it helps when the app needs root access and I don't have.

Comment: Since you said that you are not in the sudoers file (that's important to know!), you cannot install deb-based applications. Period. Deb packages are intended for system-level install (available to everybody), and cannot be installed per-user. You *can* install Snaps and Pips and Wheels and Flatpacks and AppImages and Tarballs. The method for each is, of course, different. You cannot access system-level functionality - for example, no matter how you try, VNC won't work for you since you likely lack permission to bind to TCP/UDP ports.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for the explanation. How about packages that I need for deep learning like numpy, tensorflow, Keras... are these system-level or user-level? I know some other students were running DL codes on this computer but when I tried a very simple code I got "no module named numpy" error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends upon how you are connecting to the linux machine.
If you are connecting via ssh, then ssh X forwarding means:
`ssh -Y user@server`
(or equivalent).

However, this will not work, for you have no X server running on local machine (which is Windows). You should still get a terminal though.

Next, about the part on installing apps, since you do not have any GUI, you can install apps via apt.

Do this first:

```
sudo apt install aptitude  
aptitude search <program_name>
```

This will generate a list of packages providing the program. Chose a package from the list, then:

```
sudo apt install <package_name>
```

And you are done.

Comment: I tried the command you suggested with putty. It is exactly like a terminal, nothing graphical. Is it the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: how ssh helps when you need permission to install an app ?

Comment: @Maria Yes. That is exactly how it is supposed to be. ssh will only give you a terminal on the remote machine. But the GUI works on X. Now, if X is forwarded, then a local X server should be there to accept those commands and show the ui. In perfect case, you simply execute the app (eg. /usr/bin/dolphin ) and the window appears on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

as your administrator have advised,x forwarding means we can get a graphical output through ssh.you can do it simply as,

```
ssh user@serverIPaddress -X
```

then you can try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yourPackageName
```

Comment: I am not in sudoers file so when I sudo it returns error. how ssh helps that?

Comment: can you provide the error that returns?

Comment: says my username is not in the sudoers file.

Comment: i put this answer assuming that you are using apt base linux distribution.

Comment: i put this answer assuming that you are using apt base linux distribution.
If you have not root privilages then you cannot installl packages in linux environment.Please ask admin to add ur login user to wheel group of the server.